# Popover not show up by tapping UIButton

Tags: ios, popover

I may need to show up a popover containing my own view controller when tapping a UIButton in a view, here is my code in a UIButton click method.

```
self.assetPickerPopover=[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:avc];

self.assetPickerPopover.delegate=self;

//[self.imagePickerPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
[self.imagePickerPopover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(400, 2000) animated:NO];
[self.imagePickerPopover presentPopoverFromRect:self.assetTypeButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

as you may see that I tried both methods to call out popover but both failed, even I set size of popover explicitly.

Comment: Are you using https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverPresentationController_class/ or the old popovercontroller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code sample you provided, you instantiate:

```
self.assetPickerPopover
```

But you're trying to present another object:

```
self.imagePickerPopover
```

Is it just a typo?